# Add 10 minutes to the current timestamp in java with clipping milliseconds not working

Tags: java, timestamp

I have the following code for finding the current timestamp in `java`

```
public static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentJavaSqlTimestamp() {
                    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                    return new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
```

And I call it using:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = getCurrentJavaSqlTimestamp();    
                System.out.println(timestamp);
```

I tried as follows: `System.out.println(timestamp.getTime()+10*60*1000);`

I am getting output as: **2015-12-03 14:30:56.350**

I want add 10 minutes to this and I am expecting outputs as:

**2015-12-03 14:40:56.350**

Also I do not need milli seconds in each case.

What I finally expect is:**2015-12-03 14:30:56 and 2015-12-03 14:40:56**

Comment: To add 10 minutes you need `+10*60*1000`. The value is milliseconds.

Comment: @ OldCurmudgeon its a typo error!!thanks for noting it,updated!! I am not getting in time stamp format after adding it

Comment: So is your problem *actually* just truncating the milliseconds? You seem to be adding 10 minutes with no problem at all. Please make sure your question is appropriately focused on a single problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet the problem I will explain you. 1) I am getting current time stamp as `2015-12-03 14:30:56.350` that i needed as `2015-12-03 14:30:56` without millisec in type `java.sql.Timestamp`. 2) I want to add 10 minutes to it and needed in second variable as `2015-12-03 14:40:56`. Hope now its clear to you!!

Comment: That's what you want to *do*, sure. But you only seem to have a *problem* with the first part, so the second part is completely irrelevant and shouldn't be part of your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok buddy. Please help me out to solve this!!

Comment: Please edit your question then, so it reflects the actual problem. Even if these were both problems, they should be two separate questions - a single Stack Overflow question should tackle a single issue. That makes it more useful for future visitors.

Comment: You're still adding the wrong number - you must `* 1000` not `* 100`.

Comment: More importantly, you'er still adding *at all*, which you shouldn't be, because this question should *just* be about the truncation. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints, and bear in mind that Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of useful questions and answers - that's far more important than solving your immediate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you want is a way of truncating a `Timestamp` to remove the milliseconds part. I believe that's as simple as:

```
timestamp.setNanos(0);
```

Comment: getting error  `error: 'void' type not allowed here
                                out.print(timestamp.setNanos(0));
                                                            ^
1 error`

Comment: @Santhucool: Note how my answer doesn't use `out.print` at all - it just contains a statement calling `setNanos`. But more importantly, it's vital that you *understand* the code. Did you look at the `Timestamp.setNanos()` method documentation to see why I'm calling this? Always make sure you understand an answer before you use it.